# How to find the code page ID of an Outlook message file (.msg)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, codepages, msg

I want to get the *Code Page ID* that was used when writing an email (outlook .msg file). The property that holds this information is `PidTagMessageCodepage`. But I cannot find how to access it with C++.

The message file (.msg) that I am trying to read was created on a windows machine, and system locale was set to English. This email was sent to another system which system locale is Japanese (*Shift-JIS Code Page*). I want to identify the original code page from message file and pass it to`MultiByteToWideChar()`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What access to you have to the message? Raw MSG file in filesystem? Outlook?

Comment: @Ben Raw MSG file in filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access those properties you should use Extended MAPI methods. There is a very useful library for that in CodeProject, [MAPIEx](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10881/MAPIEx-Extended-MAPI-Wrapper).

If you do not whish to use Extended MAPI, you might try to open and handle the data on the .msg file directly. .msg files are essentialy OLE2 Compound Document [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693383(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Files and you may access their properties directly by using the method StgCreateStorageEx and other related to it. In order to find out which storage or streams you have to search for, there are a few applications that support Compound File exploring. Just google it.